# jQuery .click() event has unexpected behaviour with $.post to php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is where I register the .click()

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#newRoundId").click(function() {
        if(inGame()) {
            alert(1);
            if(confirm("Are you sure?") == true) {
                alert(2);
                $.post("../php/fetch_word.php", function(word) { startNewRound(word); }, "text");
            }
        }

        else {
            alert(3);
            $.post("../php/fetch_word.php", function(word) { startNewRound(word); }, "text");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is fetch_word.php

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";

    do {
        $result = $db->query("SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
        $resultArr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $word = implode($resultArr[0]);
        $dupResult = $db->query("SELECT word FROM guessed_words WHERE word = '$word'");     
    }   while($dupResult->num_rows);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO guessed_words (word) VALUES ('$word')");

    echo $word;
?>
```

The code works fine when inGame() is false and when the confirm("Are you sure"?) is true, I get back multiple words, but it still "works", but when the confirm() is false, $.post() request is sent to the server and multiple words return, and if I keep doing it, I get a seemingly random amount of words returned, followed by a fatal error of the server request timing out for >30 seconds. Really confused, as my php code worked before, and now that I am testing it with this new .click() function, I get this.

The alert()'s are there for debugging purposes.

Comment: 1) What does `inGame()` do? 2) Not sure why you're using `$.post()` when you are not passing any data to the URL. I would think `$.get()` would be just easier.

Comment: FYI, you can combine the two `SELECT` queries. `SELECT word FROM words WHERE word NOT IN (SELECT word FROM guessed_words) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`.

Comment: The timeout is happening when you run low on words. It keeps picking a random word, noticing that it's already been guessed, and never finds an unused word. Using my combined query should prevent this problem.

Comment: I don't see any way that this could send a `$.post` request when the confirm is false.

Comment: @Twisty If there are no parameters, I don't think there's much difference between `$.post` and `$.get`.

Comment: Why are you using `implode()` when there's just a single column? Just use `$word = $resultArr[0]['word']`. And why are you using `fetch_all` when there's just a single row being returned? Just use `$row = $result=>fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC); $word = $row ? $row['word'] : '';`

Comment: I would also advise debugging via `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. This way there is no additional click events. True @Barmar

Comment: Also `if(confirm('...') == true)` can be better written as `if(confirm('...'))`

Comment: @Twist inGame() checks if they are in the game and returns true or false.

Comment: @Barmar I added the implode because I get an array to string conversion error for some reason. No idea why, but with implode everything works. Also, mysqli doesn't have fetch().

Comment: Your code without `implode` was probably not indexing it with the column name. It was probably `$word = $resultArr[0]` instead of `$word = $resultArr[0]['word']`. Don't just call random functions until the errors go away, you need to understand **why** you're getting the error and fix that.